# How to use Keycloak token between Microservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am building a application which works on microservices and I am authenticating my Gateway using Keycloak my authentication is working fine Gateway is redirecting me to Keycloak login page and login done successfully and I am able to get token Id and I am passing this Id to other Microservices but when I am making rest request to Gateway again from any other Microservice it is getting failed but I am sending token in "Authorization" in Gateway but it is not working. So how to communicate between Microservices once login done?

This is My Gateway in which I am getting token in controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/aiv")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @PostMapping(path = "/authenticate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getAuth(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data, Authentication authentication) {
       // Here it is passing to Other Microservice
        data.put("Authorization",((DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getIdToken().getTokenValue());
       String responseData = new DefaultAuthenticateImpl().authenticateByPassword(data,dataSource);
       return responseData;
    }
```

Gateway Security Service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        // Authenticate through configured OpenID Provider
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/app/").authenticated().and().cors().and().oauth2Login();

        // Also logout at the OpenID Connect provider
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));

        // Require authentication for all requests
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated();

        // Allow showing /home within a frame
        http.headers().frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.SAMEORIGIN);

        // Disable CSRF in the gateway to prevent conflicts with proxied service CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

And yml file configuration is as follow:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/Default
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            user-info-authentication-method: header
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: Default
            client-secret: 8ZRUH62PxicdfsdfsasD82VzWhvqWt03K6
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
            scope: openid
```

And now from another microservice when I am calling again it to Gateway using below rest request:

```
  public String getRequest(String stUrl, Map<String, Object> data) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpGet httpget = null;
        //Calling again Gateway to get user additional information.
        httpget = new HttpGet(<<Gateway Url>>);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = data.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = entries.next();
            httpget.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }

       // Here passing Authorization token
        httpget.setHeader("Authorization", <<AuthToken>>);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String resp = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        return resp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But this rest request getting failed I am not sure why it is getting failes even after passing "Authorization". Please help how can we communicate between microservices.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't configure the gateway as OAuth2 client: I see gateway as a layer abstracting REST APIs which are resource-servers, not clients.

Configuring gateway as OAuth2 client can be handy with browser clients which don't know anything about OAuth2 but has following implications:

- request between browser and gateway **is not OAuth2**: it is secured with sessions, not with an access-token set as Bearer authorization header. As the request is secured with sessions CSRF protection must be enabled.
- gateway links this session to an access-token. You can configure it to set this token as Authorization header before forwarding request to resource-server micro services. But what it expects from incoming requests is a session not an access token.

In your case I'd leave gateway transparent to security (nothing related to OAuth2, sessions or login): clients handle login and requests authorization by themself (with the help of [certified client libs](https://openid.net/developers/certified/)) and micro-services are configured as resource-server. In this scenario, two cases for inter micro-services calls:

- request is done without the context of the user who originated the request: serviceA calls serviceB in its own name, then serviceA uses client credentials to get a new access token
- sub-request to serciceB is made on behalf of the user who originated the request, then serviceA just forwards incoming access-token as Authorization header.